# Pass multiple arguments to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a function with 2 arguments using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

**Function:**

```
def test(var1, var2):
    return var1 + var2
```

**How do I pass `x` and `y` as the two arguments / values for this function?**

```
x = 'text1'
y = 'text2'
process = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(test, PASS_TWO_ARGUMENTS_HERE)
z = process.results()
```

I found various answers, but they all mentioned complex cases and solutions; can someone provide a simple 1-line solution for this without changing the function itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found the simplest solution- pack parameters into a list, then unpack them:

```
process = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(test, *["Text1", "Text2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` function for your purposes:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def test(var1, var2):
    return var1 + var2

params = ['text1', 'text2']
process = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(lambda p: test(*p), params)
```

Comment: I managed to simplify the code further by removing some stuff. This line replaces the two last lines:

Comment: `process = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(lambda: test('text1', 'text2'))`